# timer library using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a timer library from EasyTimer.
Every time, i start my timer, it will start from 00:00:00
How do i make my timer to start timer from `<?php echo $timer; ?>`
For example start timer from 00:00.30.
`$timer` value comes from DB.

source code: https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/#chronoHtml

PHP:

```
<!--Timer.Start-->
    Timer:
    <div id="chronoExample" class="input-group ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
        <?php if ($update == true): ?>
            <div id="timer1" class="values form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-touched"><?php echo $timer; ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div id="timer1" class="values form-control ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-touched">00:00:00</div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="startButton btn btn-default">Start</button>
            <button type="button" class="pauseButton btn btn-default">Pause</button>
            <button type="button" class="resetButton btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="javascript/easytimer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timerInstance = new Timer();
    </script>
    <script src="javascript/easytimer.js"></script>
    <input type="hidden" id="timerdata" name="timer">
    <script>
        function change() {
            document.getElementById('timerdata').value = document.getElementById('timer1').textContent;
        }
    </script>
    <!--Timer.End-->
```

Easytimer.js:

```
    var timer = new Timer();
$('#chronoExample .startButton').click(function () {
    timer.start();
});
$('#chronoExample .pauseButton').click(function () {
    timer.pause();
});
$('#chronoExample .stopButton').click(function () {
    timer.stop();
});
$('#chronoExample .resetButton').click(function () {
    timer.reset();
});
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
timer.addEventListener('started', function (e) {
    $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
timer.addEventListener('reset', function (e) {
    $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});
```

Easytimer.min.js:

```
!function (t, n) {
    "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module ? module.exports = n() : "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(n) : t.Timer = n()
}(this, function () {
    "use strict";

    function s(t, n, e) {
        var o = void 0, i = "";
        if (t.length > n) return t;
        for (o = 0; o < n; o += 1) i += String(e);
        return (i + t).slice(-i.length)
    }

    function P() {
        this.secondTenths = 0, this.seconds = 0, this.minutes = 0, this.hours = 0, this.days = 0, this.toString = function (t, n, e) {
            t = t || ["hours", "minutes", "seconds"], n = n || ":", e = e || 2;
            var o = [], i = void 0;
            for (i = 0; i < t.length; i += 1) void 0 !== this[t[i]] && ("secondTenths" === t[i] ? o.push(this[t[i]]) : o.push(s(this[t[i]], e, "0")));
            return o.join(n)
        }
    }

    var t = "undefined" != typeof window ? window.CustomEvent : void 0;
    "undefined" != typeof window && "function" != typeof t && ((t = function (t, n) {
        n = n || {bubbles: !1, cancelable: !1, detail: void 0};
        var e = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
        return e.initCustomEvent(t, n.bubbles, n.cancelable, n.detail), e
    }).prototype = window.Event.prototype, window.CustomEvent = t);
    var q = "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function (t) {
            return typeof t
        } : function (t) {
            return t && "function" == typeof Symbol && t.constructor === Symbol && t !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof t
        }, I = "secondTenths", O = "seconds", z = "minutes", R = "hours", B = "days",
        F = {secondTenths: 100, seconds: 1e3, minutes: 6e4, hours: 36e5, days: 864e5},
        G = {secondTenths: 10, seconds: 60, minutes: 60, hours: 24},
        H = "undefined" != typeof module && module.exports && "function" == typeof require ? require("events") : void 0;

    function J() {
        return "undefined" != typeof document
    }

    function K() {
        return H
    }

    function N(t, n) {
        return (t % n + n) % n
    }

    return function () {
        var s = new P, r = new P, i = void 0,
            e = J() ? document.createElement("span") : K() ? new H.EventEmitter : void 0, u = !1, d = !1, c = void 0,
            a = void 0, f = void 0, v = {}, h = void 0, l = void 0, p = void 0, m = void 0, y = void 0, o = void 0,
            b = {detail: {timer: this}};

        function w(t, n) {
            var e, o, i = r[n];
            return o = U(t, F[e = n]), r[e] = o, s[e] = e === B ? o : 0 <= o ? N(o, G[e]) : G[e] - N(o, G[e]), r[n] !== i
        }

        function t() {
            n(), function () {
                for (var t in s) s.hasOwnProperty(t) && "number" == typeof s[t] && (s[t] = 0);
                for (var n in r) r.hasOwnProperty(n) && "number" == typeof r[n] && (r[n] = 0)
            }()
        }

        function n() {
            clearInterval(i), i = void 0, d = u = !1
        }

        function g(t) {
            var n, e, o;
            M() ? (y = E(), l = V(h.target)) : (c = "string" == typeof(e = (e = t) || {}).precision ? e.precision : O, f = "function" == typeof e.callback ? e.callback : function () {
            }, m = !0 === e.countdown, a = !0 === m ? -1 : 1, "object" === q(e.startValues) ? (o = e.startValues, p = L(o), s.secondTenths = p[0], s.seconds = p[1], s.minutes = p[2], s.hours = p[3], s.days = p[4], r = A(p, r)) : p = null, y = E(), S(), "object" === q(e.target) ? l = V(e.target) : m ? (e.target = {seconds: 0}, l = V(e.target)) : l = null, v = {
                precision: c,
                callback: f,
                countdown: "object" === (void 0 === e ? "undefined" : q(e)) && !0 === e.countdown,
                target: l,
                startValues: p
            }, h = e), n = F[c], C(j(Date.now())) || (i = setInterval(T, n), d = !(u = !0))
        }

        function E() {
            return j(Date.now()) - r.secondTenths * F[I] * a
        }

        function T() {
            var t, n = j(Date.now());
            (t = S())[I] && k("secondTenthsUpdated", b), t[O] && k("secondsUpdated", b), t[z] && k("minutesUpdated", b), t[R] && k("hoursUpdated", b), t[B] && k("daysUpdated", b), f(b.detail.timer), C(n) && (D(), k("targetAchieved", b))
        }

        function S() {
            var t = 0 < arguments.length && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : j(Date.now()),
                n = 0 < a ? t - y : y - t, e = {};
            return e[I] = w(n, I), e[O] = w(n, O), e[z] = w(n, z), e[R] = w(n, R), e[B] = w(n, B), e
        }

        function j(t) {
            return Math.floor(t / F[c]) * F[c]
        }

        function C(t) {
            return l instanceof Array && o <= t
        }

        function L(t) {
            var n, e, o, i, s, r = void 0;
            if ("object" === (void 0 === t ? "undefined" : q(t))) if (t instanceof Array) {
                if (5 !== t.length) throw new Error("Array size not valid");
                r = t
            } else r = [t.secondTenths || 0, t.seconds || 0, t.minutes || 0, t.hours || 0, t.days || 0];
            return n = r[0], e = r[1] + U(n, 10), o = r[2] + U(e, 60), i = r[3] + U(o, 60), s = r[4] + U(i, 24), r[0] = n % 10, r[1] = e % 60, r[2] = o % 60, r[3] = i % 24, r[4] = s, r
        }

        function U(t, n) {
            var e = t / n;
            return e < 0 ? Math.ceil(e) : Math.floor(e)
        }

        function V(t) {
            if (t) {
                var n = A(l = L(t));
                return o = y + n.secondTenths * F[I] * a, l
            }
        }

        function A(t, n) {
            var e = n || {};
            return e.days = t[4], e.hours = 24 * e.days + t[3], e.minutes = 60 * e.hours + t[2], e.seconds = 60 * e.minutes + t[1], e.secondTenths = 10 * e.seconds + t[[0]], e
        }

        function D() {
            t(), k("stopped", b)
        }

        function k(t, n) {
            J() ? e.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(t, n)) : K() && e.emit(t, n)
        }

        function x() {
            return u
        }

        function M() {
            return d
        }

        void 0 !== this && (this.start = function (t) {
            x() || (g(t), k("started", b))
        }, this.pause = function () {
            n(), d = !0, k("paused", b)
        }, this.stop = D, this.reset = function () {
            t(), g(h), k("reset", b)
        }, this.isRunning = x, this.isPaused = M, this.getTimeValues = function () {
            return s
        }, this.getTotalTimeValues = function () {
            return r
        }, this.getConfig = function () {
            return v
        }, this.addEventListener = function (t, n) {
            J() ? e.addEventListener(t, n) : K() && e.on(t, n)
        }, this.removeEventListener = function (t, n) {
            J() ? e.removeEventListener(t, n) : K() && e.removeListener(t, n)
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EasyTimer.js Docs](https://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/#startAndTargetValuesExample) has an example of setting the start time.

Essentially, you just need to pass the start time to the timer object

```
<script>
    var timerInstance = new Timer();
    <?php if ($update == true): ?>
    timerInstance.start({precision: 'seconds', startValues: <?php echo $timer; ?>});
    <?php endif ?>
</script>
```

But you may have to change the way you store or echo the `$timer` in the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, that was useful, i know what to do know now. :D

Answer (score 1):

This is my final code, if someone need it.

```
Timer:
    <div id="chronoExample" class="input-group ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
        <div class="days input-group-addon" id="id_days"><?php if ($update == true): ?><?php echo $days; ?><?php else: ?>0<?php endif ?></div>
        <div class="hours input-group-addon" id="id_hours"><?php if ($update == true): ?><?php echo $hours; ?><?php else: ?>0<?php endif ?></div>
        <div class="minutes input-group-addon" id="id_minutes"><?php if ($update == true): ?><?php echo $minutes; ?><?php else: ?>0<?php endif ?></div>
        <div class="seconds input-group-addon" id="id_seconds"><?php if ($update == true): ?><?php echo $seconds; ?><?php else: ?>0<?php endif ?></div>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="startButton btn btn-default">Start</button>
            <button type="button" class="pauseButton btn btn-default">Pause</button>
            <button type="button" class="resetButton btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascript/easytimer.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var timer = new Timer();
        $('#chronoExample .startButton').click(function () {
            timer.start({
                precision: "seconds",
                startValues: {seconds: <?php if ($update == true): ?><?php echo $total_seconds; ?><?php else: ?>0<?php endif ?>}
            });
        });
        $('#chronoExample .pauseButton').click(function () {
            timer.pause();
        });
        $('#chronoExample .stopButton').click(function () {
            timer.stop();
        });
        $('#chronoExample .resetButton').click(function () {
            timer.reset();
        });
        timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
            $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
        });
        timer.addEventListener('started', function (e) {
            $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
        });
        timer.addEventListener('reset', function (e) {
            $('#chronoExample .values').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
        });
        timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
            $('#chronoExample .days').html(timer.getTimeValues().days);
            $('#chronoExample .hours').html(timer.getTimeValues().hours);
            $('#chronoExample .minutes').html(timer.getTimeValues().minutes);
            $('#chronoExample .seconds').html(timer.getTimeValues().seconds);
            <!--Total Seconds -->
            $('#gettingTotalValues .seconds').html(timer.getTotalTimeValues().seconds);
        });
    </script>
```